# How to change the color of corners of any rectangle drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to make something like this:

[image]

using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:color="#00c2a8"
        android:width="2dp"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
</shape>
```

But it seems we can't change color of corners so please tell me a way to do this.

Comment: I would go with 9 patch drawable. From xml it would be possible but complex

Comment: But how with a 9 patch drawable? Can you please explain.

Comment: Take small sized image of the above and use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example tool to create 9 patch

Comment: ohh but i don't have its image, as the internal part should be transparent not white...